# Multi column ORDER BY for wp_postmeta values

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Using the WP_Query function of WordPress I am able to create a query which translates to the following SQL;

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id )
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'core_event_year'
      AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'core_event_year'
      AND mt2.meta_key = 'core_event_month'
      AND mt3.meta_key = 'core_event_day' ) )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

However, I need to be able to add sort orders to the 3 elements retrieved for the wp_postmeta table. Since it is possible to ignore the WP_Query function and use an SQL statement directly, I realize this is the method I will have to take.

So my question is essentially about how the above SQL statement can be adapted to give me the ability to apply a sort order to each of the 3 columns queried from wp_postmeta. At present the query is just applying a blanket `DESC` orderby clause to all fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could create a date out of the three columns using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and order by that.

Comment: Hey Marcus, I've not come across that method before but it sounds interesting. Any chance you could give me an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply include the columns you need sorted in the `ORDER BY` clause.  It looks like you have three metadata columns that constitute year, month, and day. So try this:

```
ORDER BY mt1.meta_value DESC, 
         mt2.meta_value DESC,
         mt3.meta_value DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Now look, meta_values are text.  Your months and days (mt2, mt3) values might look like '1', '2' ... '10', '11' etc.  In that case you have to trick MySQL into thinking your values are numbers, or your sorting will come up wonky. This is easy: add zero to the text value. This will typecast your text to integer. The `TRIM()` function gets rid of leading and trailing spaces.

```
ORDER BY 0+TRIM(mt1.meta_value) DESC, 
         0+TRIM(mt2.meta_value) DESC,
         0+TRIM(mt3.meta_value) DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Or, as Marcus suggested, you could use a `DATE` object for ordering. You can make a date object out of your three metadata columns like this:

```
 STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',
                       TRIM(mt1.meta_value),
                       TRIM(mt2.meta_value),
                       TRIM(mt3_meta_value)),
             '%Y-%m-%d)
```

`CONCAT_WS` turns your three values into '2015-02-14'. Then, `STR_TO_DATE(arg,'%Y-%m-%d')` turns that string into a date.

This is cool because you can then order by it, like so:

```
 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',
                       TRIM(mt1.meta_value),
                       TRIM(mt2.meta_value),
                       TRIM(mt3_meta_value)),
             '%Y-%m-%d) DESC
```

You can also use it in WHERE clauses with date arithmetic, for example ....

```
 WHERE (thatBigDateExpression) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```

Comment: I already adapted the backend code to ensure the months were double digits. ;-)

Comment: Added explanation of `STR_TO_DATE` usage.

Comment: Does that mean its a straight swap of the 3xTRIM / metavalues with the STR_TO_DATE in the ORDER BY ?

Answer (score 0):

You can natively `ORDER BY` more than one column:

```
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.co1 DESC, wp_postmeta.co2 ASC, wp_postmeta.col3 ASC
```

[`ORDER BY` info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as simple as that since the columns can't be referenced directly in the way you demonstrate.